# What path provide in a .dtx file (located in source/ folder) to reach files located in doc/ folder?

Tags: paths, dtx, docstrip

For a class I want to upload on CTAN, I'd like the provided files to be organized as follows when installed by TeX distributions:

```
〈ROOT PATH〉/doc/latex/myclass/
    myclass.pdf
    sample/sample.tex
    sample/sample.pdf
    README
    ...
〈ROOT PATH〉/tex/latex/myclass/
    myclass.cls
    ...
〈ROOT PATH〉/source/latex/myclass
    myclass.dtx
    myclass.ins
    ...
```

where `〈ROOT PATH〉` will be the TeX distribution root path.

The source documentation file, `〈ROOT PATH〉/source/latex/myclass/myclass.dtx`, contains some code examples and "screenshots" coming from the auxiliary files:

- `〈ROOT PATH〉/doc/latex/myclass/sample/sample.tex`
- `〈ROOT PATH〉/doc/latex/myclass/sample/sample.pdf`

For maintenance reasons of the class' development version, these code examples and "screenshots" are directly imported in the `myclass.dtx` source file from the `sample.tex` and `sample.pdf` auxiliary files, thanks to something like:

```
\lstinputlisting[linerange=...-...]{〈hard coded ROOT PATH〉/doc/latex/myclass/sample/sample.pdf}
...
\includegraphics[page=...]{〈hard coded ROOT PATH〉/doc/latex/myclass/sample/sample.pdf}
```

where `〈hard coded ROOT PATH〉` is my own `texmf` tree. This works pretty well.

The trouble is that, when distributed by TeX distributions, this workflow will fail because, AFAIU, I'm likely unable to anticipate what TeX distribution `〈hard coded ROOT PATH〉` should be specified in `\lstinputlisting` and `\includegraphics` above, as it depends on:

- the TeX distributions,
- the OS.

Hence the user couldn't pro­duc­e the doc­u­men­ta­tion by run­ning the `.dtx` file.

Do you see a way to circumvent this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Unpacking

As far as I see the source is

```
myclass.dtx
```

Optionally a docstrip installation file can be provided:

```
myclass.ins
```

In my packages the `.ins` file is embedded in the `.dtx` file anyway and
I added an engine switch in `myclass.dtx`: If plain TeX is used, then
the installation driver (`myclass.ins`) is triggered and the files unpacked. LaTeX on the other hand generates the documentation.

Then the `docstrip` run generates:

```
myclass.cls
sample.tex
myclass.drv % documentation driver
myclass.ins % install driver
```

### Building the documentation

When the documentation is build, first `sample.pdf` is generated, e.g.:

```
pdflatex sample
% further runs of pdflatex, makeindex, biber, ...
% as needed to generate the final sample.
% (This also can serve as test for some basic features of the class.)
```

Then we have the prerequisites in the working directory:

```
sample.tex
sample.pdf
```

And `myclass.dtx` only uses the file names:

```
\lstinputlisting[linerange=...-...]{sample.tex}
\includegraphics[page=...]{sample.pdf}
```

The main documentation is compiled:

```
pdflatex myclass.drv
% pdflatex, makeindex, biber, bibtex, ...
```

### TDS installation

In the next step the files are sorted into the TDS tree:

```
myclass.dtx → TDS:source/latex/myclass/myclass.dtx
myclass.ins → TDS:source/latex/myclass/myclass.ins
myclass.cls → TDS:tex/latex/myclass/myclass.cls
myclass.pdf → TDS:doc/latex/myclass/myclass.pdf
```

If there are many sample files:

```
sample.tex  → TDS:doc/latex/myclass/sample/sample.tex
sample.pdf  → TDS:doc/latex/myclass/sample/sample.pdf
```

For just two sample files, I consider a separate directory for samples
an unnecessary complication:

```
sample.tex  → TDS:doc/latex/myclass/sample.tex
sample.pdf  → TDS:doc/latex/myclass/sample.pdf
```

### CTAN upload

If the `TDS:` is an empty directory `texmf`, then you can easily generate
`myclass.tds.zip` for CTAN:install/macros/latex/contrib/myclass.tds.zip:

```
(cd texmf && zip -9r ../myclass.tds.zip *)
```

For the CTAN upload, you will need a fresh directory `myclass`. There goes
the files that should appear in `CTAN:macros/latex/contrib/myclass/`, eg.:

```
cp myclass.{dtx,ins,pdf} myclass/
```

Also a file `README` is preferred by CTAN. Unhappily docstrip (TeX) cannot easily generate file names without extension, because the default extension `.tex` kicks in:
* Thus `README` can be a separate file that goes into:

```
    README → TDS:doc/latex/myclass/README
    README → myclass/README
```

- If it should be embedded into the `.dtx` file, then it could be named `readme.txt` or `00readme.txt` and renamed for CTAN, e.g.:

  ```
  00readme.txt → myclass/README
  ```

Now all components for the CTAN upload are present to generate `myclass.zip` for the upload:

```
zip -9r myclass.zip myclass/ myclass.tds.zip
```

### Remarks

- The user, who only wants to regenerate the documentation starts with the initial steps, until `myclass.pdf` is build.
- Also I would avoid installed files of `myclass` for compiling the documentation. Otherwise the risk rises that files from an older `myclass` installation with a different version are used by accident.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé: Most `.dtx` files I have seen contain a docstrip tag section `%<*driver>` ... `%</driver>` that is written by the `.ins` file to a file `.drv` and contains the code to generate the documentation (`\documentclass{ltxdoc}`...). But generating a separate `.drv` file is not necessarily mandatory.