# Variant of DocStrip's \file that doesn't add .tex extension

Tags: ctan, docstrip

For a class I want to upload on CTAN, several files are generated thanks to `DocStrip`'s utility:

```
\generate{\file{⟨output⟩}{\from{⟨input⟩}{⟨optionlist⟩}}}
```

Quoting Heiko Oberdiek in [What path provide in a .dtx file (located in source/ folder) to reach files located in doc/ folder?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179930/what-path-provide-in-a-dtx-file-located-in-source-folder-to-reach-files-loca):

> Unhappily docstrip (TeX) cannot easily generate file names without extension, because the default extension .tex kicks in[.]

For `⟨output⟩` supposed to be extension-less, this is a piece of pain: before sending to CTAN, one has to not forget to rename generated files from `⟨output⟩.tex` to `⟨output⟩`. Common files concerned are for `⟨output⟩ = README`  but, in my use case, `⟨output⟩ = latexmkrc` files are concerned as well.

Because of this CTAN requirement (`.tex` extension of `README.tex` files not welcome), wouldn't it be possible for `DocStrip` program to provide a star variant of `\file` such that, if `⟨output⟩` does contain any extension:

```
\generate{\file*{⟨output⟩}{\from{⟨input⟩}{⟨optionlist⟩}}}
```

generates a file named `⟨output⟩`, and not `⟨output⟩.tex`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a DocStrip limitation: it's a TeX one. TeX will *always* add `.tex` if there is no extension. For example, try

```
\newwrite\mywrite
\immediate\openout\mywrite foo %
\bye
```

(You can do `\immediate\openout\mywrite foo. %`, but the file ends up called `foo.` not just `foo`.)

The normal approach to this is to use a script for building for CTAN, which has the advantage of making sure you don't forget steps. Such a script can easily deal with the renaming. See for a 'rich' example the [LaTeX3 release script](https://github.com/latex3/svn-mirror/blob/master/support/l3make.lua) (written in Lua).

(Note: with LuaTX you could do a Lua-based file write to avoid the extension, but that of course is not applicable if you want a 'pure TeX' solution usable with pdfTeX/XeTeX.)